# Horizontal scrollbar not selectable (on Linux?)

Tags: css, html

I have a [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) [template](https://github.com/digitalcraftsman/hugo-material-docs) I am attempting to use. However, certain divs attempt to scroll horizontally, but on Chrome or Firefox on Linux I cannot manipulate the horizontal scroll bar. The horizontally scroll bar is present and looks normal, but I cannot move the slider.

Why is horizontal scrolling not working correctly on some browsers/OSes?

Interestingly, this appears to not be an issue on Chrome or FF when running Mac, which leads me to believe it's some kind of bizarre platform issue.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <article id="ARTICLE_1">
        <div id="DIV_2">
            <h1 id="H1_3">Getting started <a href="#" id="A_4" title=
            "Permanent link">#</a></h1>
            <h2 id="H2_5">Installation<a href="#installation" id="A_6" title=
            "Permanent link">#</a></h2>
            <h3 id="H3_7">Installing Hugo<a href="#installing-hugo" id="A_8" title=
            "Permanent link">#</a></h3>
            <p id="P_9">Hugo itself is just a single binary without dependencies on
            expensive runtimes like Ruby, Python or PHP and without dependencies on any
            databases. You just need to download the <a href=
            "https://github.com/spf13/hugo/releases" id="A_10">latest version</a>. For
            more information read the official <a href=
            "http://gohugo.io/overview/installing/" id="A_11">installation
            guides</a>.</p>
            <p id="P_12">Let’s make sure Hugo is set up as expected. You should see a
            similar version number in your terminal:</p>
            <pre id="PRE_13"><code class="language-sh hljs bash" id=
            "CODE_14">hugo version
    <span class="hljs-comment" id=
"SPAN_15"># Hugo Static Site Generator v0.15 BuildDate: 2016-01-03T12:47:47+01:00</span>
    </code>
    </pre>
            <h3 id="H3_16">Installing Material<a href="#installing-material" id="A_17"
            title="Permanent link">#</a></h3>
            <p id="P_18">Next, assuming you have Hugo up and running the <code id=
            "CODE_19">hugo-material-docs</code> theme can be installed with <code id=
            "CODE_20">git</code> :</p>
            <pre id="PRE_21"><code class="language-sh hljs bash" id=
            "CODE_22"><span class="hljs-comment" id=
            "SPAN_23"># create a new Hugo website</span>
    hugo new site my-awesome-docs

    <span class="hljs-comment" id=
"SPAN_24"># move into the themes folder of your website</span>
    <span class="hljs-built_in" id="SPAN_25">cd</span> my-awesome-docs/themes/

    <span class="hljs-comment" id="SPAN_26"># download the theme</span>
    git <span class="hljs-built_in" id=
"SPAN_27">clone</span> git@github.com:digitalcraftsman/hugo-material-docs.git

    long line aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    </code>
    </pre>
            <h2 id="H2_28">Setup<a href="#setup" id="A_29" title=
            "Permanent link">#</a></h2>
            <p id="P_30">Next, take a look in the <code id="CODE_31">exampleSite</code>
            folder at <code id="CODE_32">themes/hugo-material-docs/</code> . This
            directory contains an example config file and the content that you are
            currently reading. It serves as an example setup for your documentation.</p>
            <p id="P_33">Copy at least the <code id="CODE_34">config.toml</code> in the
            root directory of your website. Overwrite the existing config file if
            necessary.</p>
            <p id="P_35">Hugo includes a development server, so you can view your
            changes as you go - very handy. Spin it up with the following command:</p>
            <pre id="PRE_36"><code class="language-sh hljs bash" id=
            "CODE_37">hugo server
    </code>
    </pre>
            <p id="P_38">Now you can go to <a href="http://localhost:1313" id=
            "A_39">localhost:1313</a> and the Material theme should be visible. You can
            now start writing your documentation, or read on and customize the theme
            through some options.</p>
            <aside id="ASIDE_40">
                © 2017 Released under the MIT license – Documentation built with <a href=
                "https://www.gohugo.io" id="A_41">Hugo</a> using the <a href=
                "http://github.com/digitalcraftsman/hugo-material-docs" id=
                "A_42">Material</a> theme.
            </aside>
            <footer id="FOOTER_43">
                <nav id="NAV_44">
                    <div id="DIV_45"></div>
                    <div id="DIV_46">
                        <a href="http://localhost:1313/adding-content/" id="A_47" title=
                        "Adding content"><span id="SPAN_48">Next</span></a>
                        <div id="DIV_49">
                            <div id="DIV_50">
                                <div id="DIV_51">
                                    Adding content
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="DIV_52">
                                <i id="I_53"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#DIV_1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    height: 808px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 699px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    perspective-origin: 349.5px 404px;
    transform-origin: 349.5px 404px;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588) none 0px;
    padding: 128px 24px 96px;
}

/*#DIV_1*/

#H1_2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    height: 95px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 651px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    perspective-origin: 325.5px 47.5px;
    transform-origin: 325.5px 47.5px;
    border-top: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    font: normal normal normal normal 24px / 32px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(232, 78, 64) none 0px;
    padding: 20px 0px 42px;
}

/*#H1_2*/

#A_3 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 9.34375px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    perspective-origin: 4.67188px 16px;
    transform-origin: 4.67188px 16px;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 32px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824) none 0px;
    transition: color 0.25s ease 0s;
}

/*#A_3*/

#H2_4, #H2_13 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    height: 128px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 651px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    perspective-origin: 325.5px 64px;
    transform-origin: 325.5px 64px;
    border: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    font: normal normal normal normal 20px / 28px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: -64px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(232, 78, 64) none 0px;
    padding: 100px 0px 0px;
}

/*#H2_4, #H2_13*/

#A_5, #A_14 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 9.34375px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    perspective-origin: 4.67188px 14px;
    transform-origin: 4.67188px 14px;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 28px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824) none 0px;
    transition: color 0.25s ease 0s;
}

/*#A_5, #A_14*/

#H3_6 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    height: 107px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 651px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    perspective-origin: 325.5px 53.5px;
    transform-origin: 325.5px 53.5px;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    font: normal normal bold normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: -64px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588) none 0px;
    padding: 84px 0px 0px;
}

/*#H3_6*/

#A_7 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 9.34375px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    perspective-origin: 4.67188px 11.5px;
    transform-origin: 4.67188px 11.5px;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824) none 0px;
    transition: color 0.25s ease 0s;
}

/*#A_7*/

#P_8 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    height: 46px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 651px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    perspective-origin: 325.5px 23px;
    transform-origin: 325.5px 23px;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 21px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588) none 0px;
}

/*#P_8*/

#CODE_9, #CODE_10 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    column-rule-color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    background: rgb(238, 238, 238) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px "Ubuntu Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    outline: rgb(232, 78, 64) none 0px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}

/*#CODE_9, #CODE_10*/

#PRE_11 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    height: 78px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 699px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    perspective-origin: 349.5px 39px;
    transform-origin: 349.5px 39px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0470588) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 21px "Ubuntu Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    margin: 21px -24px 0px;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588) none 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 21px 24px;
}

/*#PRE_11*/

#CODE_12 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    display: block;
    height: 36px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 651px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    perspective-origin: 325.5px 18px;
    transform-origin: 325.5px 18px;
    background: rgb(238, 238, 238) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 21px "Ubuntu Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) none 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}

/*#CODE_12*/

#P_15 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    height: 23px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 651px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    perspective-origin: 325.5px 11.5px;
    transform-origin: 325.5px 11.5px;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 21px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588) none 0px;
}

/*#P_15*/

#ASIDE_16 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541176);
    height: 23px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 651px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541176);
    perspective-origin: 325.5px 11.5px;
    transform-origin: 325.5px 11.5px;
    border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541176);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 21px 0px 64px;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.541176) none 0px;
}

/*#ASIDE_16*/

#A_17, #A_18 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    border-top: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(232, 78, 64);
    border-left: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(232, 78, 64) none 0px;
    transition: color 0.25s ease 0s;
}

/*#A_17, #A_18*/

#FOOTER_19 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 96px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 867px;
    width: 961px;
    z-index: 4;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 480.5px 48px;
    transform-origin: 480.5px 48px;
    background: rgb(232, 78, 64) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 8px;
}

/*#FOOTER_19*/

#NAV_20 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 96px;
    max-width: 1184px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 945px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 472.5px 48px;
    transform-origin: 472.5px 48px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 8px 0px;
}

/*#NAV_20*/

#DIV_21 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 472.5px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 236.25px 40px;
    transform-origin: 236.25px 40px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}

/*#DIV_21*/

#DIV_22 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 472.5px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 236.25px 40px;
    transform-origin: 236.25px 40px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}

/*#DIV_22*/

#A_23 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 472.5px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    perspective-origin: 236.25px 40px;
    transform-origin: 236.25px 40px;
    border: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(232, 78, 64) none 0px;
    transition: color 0.25s ease 0s;
}

/*#A_23*/

#SPAN_24 {
    bottom: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.701961);
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 20px;
    width: 472.5px;
    column-rule-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.701961);
    perspective-origin: 236.25px 10px;
    transform-origin: 236.25px 10px;
    border: 0px none rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.701961);
    font: normal normal normal normal 15px / 20px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.701961) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 56px;
}

/*#SPAN_24*/

#DIV_25 {
    bottom: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    display: table;
    height: 48px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5px;
    text-align: right;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 28px;
    width: 472px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    perspective-origin: 236px 24px;
    transform-origin: 236px 24px;
    border: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(232, 78, 64) none 0px;
}

/*#DIV_25*/

#DIV_26 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    display: table;
    height: 47px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 424px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(232, 78, 64);
    perspective-origin: 212px 23.5px;
    transform-origin: 212px 23.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(232, 78, 64);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(232, 78, 64) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 8px;
}

/*#DIV_26*/

#DIV_27 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: table-cell;
    height: 47px;
    text-align: right;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 408px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 204px 23.5px;
    transform-origin: 204px 23.5px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 18px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 11px 0px 13px;
}

/*#DIV_27*/

#DIV_28 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: table-cell;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: right;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 48px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 24px 24px;
    transform-origin: 24px 24px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 23.8px Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}

/*#DIV_28*/

#I_29 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    speak: none;
    text-align: right;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    perspective-origin: 20px 20px;
    transform-origin: 20px 20px;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    font: normal normal normal normal 24px / 24px Icon;
    margin: 4px;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    transition: background 0.25s ease 0s;
}

/*#I_29*/

#I_29:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    content: '""';
    speak: none;
    text-align: right;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 24px / 24px Icon;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}

/*#I_29:before*/
```

Comment: Code in your question. With 5K+ rep you should know this by now.

Comment: @j08691 The entire source is in the linked demo. Since I can't isolate the problem, I don't know which portions are relevant. Short of pasting 1500 lines of CSS into the question, a live demo will have to suffice.

Comment: even in windows doesnt work for chrome

Comment: did you notice, if you disable `/* display: block; */` of `.hljs ` rule you have a working scrollable bar

Comment: i've found the problem ... ;)

Comment: @andrepaulo Doesn't work for me still on Linux at least... tried removing `highlight.css` entirely before and I still have a scrollbar I can't manipulate.

Comment: @JeffMixon check the answer

Comment: At 5k, you should know that "I can't isolate the problem" isn't a valid excuse to have the code off-site. Reread [mcve]. Use those strategies. Don't make the question break when you decide to move that page, or stop paying for server hosting, or change domain name, or fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is causing your problem.

```
.article h2 {
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top: -64px;
}
```

Your H2 tag is overlapping the horizontal bar. So you should balance these numbers, I would do:

```
.article h2 {
    padding-top: 36px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Seems not affect your design. And respecting the previous proportion.

Make sure to change also your `@media` areas too.

EDIT: How I've discovered the problem, using the devTools. I realized the size of your `h2` was overlapping.
[image]

Comment: Ugh. For whatever reason I didn't think the browser would let something overlap the scrollbar like that so I didn't even consider it. Thanks for the help.